# Sorting a Vector by Mod with Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I' m trying different things with the lambda operator for understanding.
Now I'm hanging at a point.

I want to sort a vector by modulo 5 like this:

First all `int`'s with remainder `0`, then remainder `1`, remainder `2` .... remainder `4`

Input:

> ```
> 12,6,32,33,17,21,9,10,2,8,20
> ```

Output

> ```
> 10,20,21,6,12,32,17,2,33,8,9
> ```

Is that what i want possible?
And if yes can you give me a hint how?

I alread found the sort operator and tried a few things like normal sorting:

```
    void order(vector<int> vec){
       sort(begin(vec), end(vec), 
       [](int i, int j) {
           return (i < j);
       }
    );
```

Just for proof i already did something^^

Comment: Well then, how do you compute the remainder of a number after division?

Comment: *Just for proof i already did something* yes you have the boiler plate.  Did you try to get the remainder of the two numbers and compare them to each other?

Comment: I think a good place to start would be by looking into the documentation for [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: You know about the `%` modulo operator?

Comment: _@Drizzt_ "Just for proof i already did something^^" That's just a ridiculous statement. If such counts everyone could come here with a `int main() {}` and say _Look what I've done, could u gimme teh codez goin inside the `{}` plz._.

Comment: @KerrekSB _Rest_ => [german (2nd match)](https://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Rest&searchLoc=1&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) => [english (1st match)](https://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Rest&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) :-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ true that, it was a stupid sentence. And i already had a the % modulo operator (believe me or not) i just could not get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `%` modulo operator.

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
           [](int a, int b) { return std::abs(a % 5) < std::abs(b % 5); });
```

Comment: And add a comparison when the remainders are the same.

Comment: @stefaanv right, but looks like op didn't ask about it, all though hist output says he wants it.

Comment: what is an op?  I didnt know i could put statements in the return statement.

Comment: @Drizzt OP is the person asked question, so you are OP here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by remainder and with the same remainder by value you can use this:

```
void order(vector<int> vec){
   sort(begin(vec), end(vec), 
   [](int i, int j) {
       return std::make_tuple( std::abs( i % 5 ), i ) < std::make_tuple( std::abs( j % 5 ), j );
   }
);
```